# Radius of Convergence on Power Series Help

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am struggling to find the radii of convergence of the following two series:

$$\sum_{n}n^{\cos(n)}z^n$$

$$\sum_{n}(2^{-n} + 3^{-n})z^n$$

Here  I tried using ratio test and lim sup, but didn't get anywhere.

I know $n^{\cos(n)}$ is bounded by $n^{-1}$ and $n$ . How does this help us with radii of convergence?

Thanks

Comment: For the first, the limsup of the (absolute value) of the $n$-th root is $|z|$.

Comment: Use the root test on the first, comparison / root test on the second

Comment: Can you expand on how exactly we can do the root test/comparison test on these two

Answer (score 0):

For the first, use Hadamard's test
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|n^{\cos n}|^{1/n}=1/R\Rightarrow  
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|n^{(\cos n)/n}|=1=1/R\Rightarrow R=1$$
Since $1/n(\cos n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

For the second, note that the $\sqrt[n]{}$ is a concave function so 
$$ (s+t)^{1/n}\leq s^{1/n}+t^{1/n} $$
Whenever $s,t>0$. So this yields
$$ |2^{-n}+3^{-n}|^{1/n}\leq |2^{-n}|^{1/n}+|3^{-n}|^{1/n}\Rightarrow 1/R=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup|2^{-n}+3^{-n}|^{1/n} \\
\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup|2^{-n}|^{1/n}+\sup|3^{-n}|^{1/n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{5}{6}\Rightarrow 1/R\leq 5/6 $$
And $R\geq 6/5$.

Comment: The solutions state that the  Radius of Convergence of convergence is 2?

Comment: @Shalid Hey I only promised you it was bigger than 6/5 :) ... sorry that is the best I can do at the moment, I will keep thinking.

Comment: no worries, thank you :)

Comment: We have $2^{-n}\lt 2^{-n}+3^{-n}\le 2\cdot 2^{-n}$. Taking $n$-th roots we get $2^{-1}\lt (2^{-n}+3^{-n})^{1/n}\le 2^{1/n}2^{-1}$. Let $n\to \infty$ and use squeezing to conclude that the limit of our $n$-th root is $2^{-1}$.